# How can I convert a PDF to an editable Visio file?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-visio, image-conversion

I have old PDF document (image of a map), and I want to import it into Visio to edit/update it.  What is the basic workflow to follow. Attached is sample PDF. Is there a way to trace the lines/shapes automatically and make them editable Visio files? I have the ability to convert PDF to any file.

[Sample PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cj5iv7if6cyq3hd/519.pdf?dl=0)

Image on the PDF page:
[image: PDF image]

Update: 
Understood. The end product is that I am trying to create the Map that is originally in the format of .CRW (Corel Draw) as seen above  and create the end product like this map.

[image]
. The new map used visio to create - just trying to find out workflow how to get from the first crappy map to the version that is cleaned in visio - oh yea there are over 200 maps so trying to figure a streamlined process

Comment: I know curiosity gets the better of everyone but it's probably wise not to download that link

Comment: visio? PDF? what the heck! Is there any relationship?

Comment: Just to note, its a legitimate pdf, of an old map - did a quick check with linux and virustotal https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/7a4ddb0d1a299df4ec46ac546a6f4d619c643f958570a84eacb3322313f8513f/analysis/

Comment: Low score, dropbox link, incorrect formatting, name of question - just seemed to check too many "DANGER WILL ROBINSON, DANGER" boxes. Fair play.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what formats Visio can handle.  Can you convert from bitmap to vector and have Visio handle it (or use a vector image editor)?  Or just use a decent bitmap image editor?  Photoshop will open a PDF.

Answer (score 3):

Your drawing looks like a scanned picture actually (bitmap). It's not important if it is wrapped in PDF or whatever, the important part is that it is "just" a picture. First you'll probably need to vectorize it (so that it contains "shapes").

That is, Visio is a pure vector-graphic drawing tool. It does not have vectorization capabilities (conversion from a picture to vector graphics). You may need to use some other tool, and then convert whatever you get from that tool to Visio. You could try [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html) for example (it has "vectorization" function), or some professional tool / online service for that.

The best could be if you can get the "source" of the picture you have in PDF in some vector format (SVG for example).

In my opinion, what you are trying to do is next to impossible. it could be easier just to draw the map from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Visio can't work directly with PDF files. Either get a PDF file editor, or convert the PDF into DXF format (there are free converters available for that job), then import the DXF file into Visio.

Answer (score 2):

A True PDF can be converted to an editable Visio (VSD) file - I have done it many times.

1. Convert PDF to an SVG file (there are many free converters available online - but you can also use Adobe Illustrator to convert it)
2. Once converted open the SVG in Visio.
3. Save the SVG file in Visio as a VSD file. Remember to ungroup all lines and objects before editing the new VSD file

BUT - if you do not have a true PDF file it can not be converted into an editable file.

Comment: -1 for using a term that is rarely used without an explanation.

Comment: "True PDF" probably means "Not a scanned image", which you won't be able to edit.

Comment: That's actually called "a vector-based PDF".